# AngularJS "global" data?

Tags: angularjs

I'm creating a web app with angular. Users can log in and send messages to other users.

What's the best way of globally storing information about the logged in user - e.g. their username, ID, picture URL, etc? Or do I need to send it as part of the JSON data used to render each page?

Comment: Hi, good question, even though it is not a good practice to store anything in the $rootScope, this (sort of) global stuff can reside in there.
So, inject $rootScope to any of your controllers, like:
`YourModule.controllers('myCtrl, function ($scope, $rootScope)')`
and it will be accessible to any controller.
Or you can use a separate service for that purpose as well...

Comment: Dont litter the $rootScope. He might as well just store the info on window...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Angular" way to do this, is to use something called a Service

See this video by the amazing John Linguist, for more information on how to achieve this

http://egghead.io/video/angularjs-sharing-data-between-controllers/

Comment: Link is not working anymore, here's the new one https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-sharing-data-between-controllers